# How to control which users can see which videos

Tags: apache-flex

Imagine you have a large number of video files stored on a server, and a Flex app which lets users play those videos they have access to. How can you best set this up? Wouldn't the Flex app just be sent the name of the video to play... in which case couldn't someone else write another flex app if they knew the file names? Can Flex play videos hosted on other sites? Is there some clever piece on the server I'm missing, which sits between the Flex video player and the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask users to log-in with a username and password - you can use [OpenID](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#php) if you want.

Update:
Set the [crossdomain.xml](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html) of [your server](http://www.flashperfection.com/tutorials/Flash-Cross-Domain-Access-85118.html) in such a way that [only Flash movies](http://www.youtube.com/crossdomain.xml) from [your domain](http://twitter.com/crossdomain.xml) can access content from there.

Comment: How does logging in make any difference? That just means the Flex app is told a different list of videos, it's still able to show them if it knew the name.

Comment: Use a crossdomain.xml file - Flash movies from other servers won't be able to access content from your site unless you allow them to do it through a crossdomain.xml.

Comment: So this is a safe approach: 1)store a load of files in a dir on the server. 2)when user logs in, server sends a list of files names they can see. 3)client loads videos from this list... so even though it would be easy for a hacker to find the file names, they couldn't create their own Flex app because the server wouldn't let the files be used from another site?

Comment: Exactly. And if you implement log-in mechanism, unregistered users won't be able to see them even through your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a server-side script (in PHP or something else) that serves the file only if your user is allowed to see it (how to determine that you'll have to come up with yourself). This is a bit of a performance hit, although not so much if you use PHP's `readfile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can Flex play videos hosted on other sites?

Your crossdomain.xml can control this. e.g. myvideoserver.com/crossdomain.xml would contain entries based on who you want to grant access to, like myflexserver.com. Then just ripping off your main flex application wouldn't give them access to your video files.